# How to tell if a stream is actually gzipped

Tags: php, gzip

## Background

This question is to do with gzip, specifically: php functions such as `gzinflate`

Setup:

- php8.2
- wordpress system

I have a wordpress plugin. It loads a stream from a third party provider. This provider sends json for information and my plugin parses it.

However, they seem to be inconsistent with their application of gzip. All headers claim that `content-type` is `application/x-gzip`, but it isn't. Some streams parse without running `gzinflate()`.

### Question

How do I *actually check* if something is gzip compressed.

(I am thinking about something like: `if(gzipped($data)) { ... }`)

Comment: How are you getting the data from the 3rd party? Libraries like curl and Guzzle will decompress transparently.

Comment: The first 2 bytes of a gzip file are `0x1f 0x8b`.

Comment: If the provider sends JSON, then the `Content-Type` has to say `application/json`. This is not to be confused with [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) which may be gzip and contain the JSON (in most cases a gzip encoded content is handled transparently by whatever library you use to get the data so you may no need to actually decompress it in code). If they claim they are sending a content type of gzip but it's actually JSON you need to contact them so they conform to standard

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm using wordpress'  function `wp_remote_get()` - it doesn't auto decompress. This is why for some feeds they are compressed, not so in other cases.

Comment: @apokryfos I may do this, but it will be lost in a 12 month delay and not solve the problem now.

Comment: `wp_remote_get()` takes `decompress=true` as an argument. See [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-http.php).

Answer (score 0):

By actually trying to decompress it as a gzip stream. If it fails, then it's not gzipped. That will generally determine very quickly, usually within the first few bytes, that it's not gzipped.

`gzinflate()` however does *not* decompress gzip streams. **`gzdecode()` does that.** `gzinflate()` decompresses raw deflate streams. `gzuncompress()` decompresses zlib streams. (I didn't come up with these confusing and misleading names.)